# Buildozer Cannot Connect To S3 Endpoint Logcat Error

Tags: python, android, kivy, logcat, buildozer

I have the follow error in my logcat return when I try to run a program packaged with Kivy and buildozer. I can run this same code on my PC and it works no issues, no clue what I'm missing.

```
01-29 08:17:14.328 28372 31003 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/client.py", line 682, in _make_request
01-29 08:17:14.328 28372 31003 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
01-29 08:17:14.328 28372 31003 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/endpoint.py", line 136, in _send_request
01-29 08:17:14.328 28372 31003 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/endpoint.py", line 253, in _needs_retry
01-29 08:17:14.329 28372 31003 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/hooks.py", line 356, in emit
01-29 08:17:14.329 28372 31003 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/hooks.py", line 228, in emit
01-29 08:17:14.329 28372 31003 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
01-29 08:17:14.329 28372 31003 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__
01-29 08:17:14.329 28372 31003 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 250, in __call__
01-29 08:17:14.330 28372 31003 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 277, in _should_retry
01-29 08:17:14.330 28372 31003 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 316, in __call__
01-29 08:17:14.330 28372 31003 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 222, in __call__
01-29 08:17:14.330 28372 31003 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
01-29 08:17:14.330 28372 31003 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/endpoint.py", line 200, in _do_get_response
01-29 08:17:14.330 28372 31003 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/endpoint.py", line 269, in _send
01-29 08:17:14.331 28372 31003 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/httpsession.py", line 337, in send
01-29 08:17:14.331 28372 31003 I python  :  botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://totals2.s3.amazonaws.com/totals.json"
01-29 08:17:14.331 28372 31003 I python  : Python for android ended.
01-29 08:21:01.180 30098 31302 I python  : set wchar paths...
01-29 08:21:01.228 30098 31302 I python  : Initialized python
01-29 08:21:01.228 30098 31302 I python  : AND: Init threads
01-29 08:21:01.228 30098 31302 I python  : testing python print redirection
01-29 08:21:01.229 30098 31302 I python  : Android path ['.', '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/stdlib.zip', '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/modules', '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages']
01-29 08:21:01.229 30098 31302 I python  : os.environ is environ({'PATH': '/sbin:/system/sbin:/product/bin:/apex/com.android.runtime/bin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/odm/bin:/vendor/bin:/vendor/xbin', 'MOUNT_SYSTEM_OK': 'true', 'ANDROID_BOOTLOGO': '1', 'ANDROID_ROOT': '/system', 'ANDROID_ASSETS': '/system/app', 'ANDROID_DATA': '/data', 'ANDROID_STORAGE': '/storage', 'ANDROID_RUNTIME_ROOT': '/apex/com.android.runtime', 'ANDROID_TZDATA_ROOT': '/apex/com.android.tzdata', 'EXTERNAL_STORAGE': '/sdcard', 'ASEC_MOUNTPOINT': '/mnt/asec', 'BOOTCLASSPATH': '/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-libart.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/okhttp.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/bouncycastle.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/knoxsdk.jar:/system/framework/knoxanalyticssdk.jar:/system/framework/smartbondingservice.jar:/system/framework/securetimersdk.jar:/system/framework/fipstimakeystore.jar:/system/framework/timakeystore.jar:/system/framework/sec_sdp_sdk.jar:/system/framework/sec_sdp_hidden_sdk.jar:/system/framework/drutils.jar:/system/framework/android.test.base.jar:/system/framework/ucmopensslenginehelper.jar:/system/framework/esecomm.jar:/system/framework/tcmiface.jar:/system/framework/QPerformance.jar:/system/framework/UxPerformance.jar:/apex/com.android.conscrypt/javalib/conscrypt.jar:/apex/com.android.media/javalib/updatable-media.jar', 'DEX2OATBOOTCLASSPATH': '/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-libart.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/okhttp.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/bouncycastle.jar:/apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/voip-common.jar:/system/framework/ims-common.jar:/system/framework/knoxsdk.jar:/system/framework/knoxanalyticssdk.jar:/system/framework/smartbondingservice.jar:/system/framework/securetimersdk.jar:/system/framework/fipstimakeystore.jar:/system/framework/timakeystore.jar:/system/framework/sec_sdp_sdk.jar:/system/framework/sec_sdp_hidden_sdk.jar:/system/framework/drutils.jar:/system/framework/android.test.base.jar:/system/framework/ucmopensslenginehelper.jar:/system/framework/esecomm.jar:/system/framework/tcmiface.jar:/system/framework/QPerformance.jar:/system/framework/UxPerformance.jar', 'SYSTEMSERVERCLASSPATH': '/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/ethernet-service.jar:/system/framework/wifi-service.jar:/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar:/system/framework/uibc_java.jar:/system/framework/ssrm.jar', 'DOWNLOAD_CACHE': '/data/cache', 'KNOX_STORAGE': '/data/knox/ext_sdcard', 'ENC_EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET': '/storage/enc_emulated', 'ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote_secondary': '19', 'ANDROID_SOCKET_usap_pool_secondary': '22', 'ANDROID_ENTRYPOINT': 'main.pyc', 'ANDROID_ARGUMENT': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app', 'ANDROID_APP_PATH': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app', 'ANDROID_PRIVATE': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files', 'ANDROID_UNPACK': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app', 'PYTHONHOME': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app', 'PYTHONPATH': '/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app:/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/lib', 'PYTHONOPTIMIZE': '2', 'P4A_BOOTSTRAP': 'SDL2', 'PYTHON_NAME': 'python', 'P4A_IS_WINDOWED': 'True', 'P4A_ORIENTATION': 'portrait', 'P4A_NUMERIC_VERSION': 'None', 'P4A_MINSDK': '21', 'LC_CTYPE': 'C.UTF-8'})
01-29 08:21:01.229 30098 31302 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
01-29 08:21:01.229 30098 31302 I python  : AND: Ran string
01-29 08:21:01.229 30098 31302 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
01-29 08:21:01.291 30098 31302 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 21)
01-29 08:21:01.291 30098 31302 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
01-29 08:21:01.295 30098 31302 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_21-01-29_0.txt
01-29 08:21:01.295 30098 31302 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
01-29 08:21:01.295 30098 31302 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyc"
01-29 08:21:01.295 30098 31302 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.1 (default, Jan 28 2021, 21:52:17)
01-29 08:21:01.295 30098 31302 I python  : [Clang 8.0.2 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/clang 40173bab62ec7462
01-29 08:21:01.295 30098 31302 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at ""
01-29 08:21:01.639 30098 31302 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
01-29 08:21:01.659 30098 31302 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
01-29 08:21:01.787 30098 31302 I python  : [INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] v0.104.1
01-29 08:21:01.797 30098 31302 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
01-29 08:21:01.811 30098 31302 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
01-29 08:21:01.812 30098 31302 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
01-29 08:21:01.812 30098 31302 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 V@415.0 (GIT@128c575, I000594fe7d, 1580716718) (Date:02/02/20)'>
01-29 08:21:01.812 30098 31302 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Qualcomm'>
01-29 08:21:01.812 30098 31302 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Adreno (TM) 640'>
01-29 08:21:01.812 30098 31302 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
01-29 08:21:01.812 30098 31302 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
01-29 08:21:01.812 30098 31302 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
01-29 08:21:01.828 30098 31302 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
01-29 08:21:01.829 30098 31302 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
01-29 08:21:01.839 30098 31302 I python  : [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
01-29 08:21:01.895 30098 31302 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
01-29 08:21:03.078 30098 31302 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
01-29 08:21:03.078 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/urllib3/connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
01-29 08:21:03.078 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
01-29 08:21:03.078 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/python3/Lib/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
01-29 08:21:03.079 30098 31302 I python  :  socket.gaierror: [Errno 7] No address associated with hostname
01-29 08:21:03.079 30098 31302 I python  :  
01-29 08:21:03.079 30098 31302 I python  :  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
01-29 08:21:03.079 30098 31302 I python  :  
01-29 08:21:03.079 30098 31302 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
01-29 08:21:03.079 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/httpsession.py", line 308, in send
01-29 08:21:03.080 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
01-29 08:21:03.080 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 506, in increment
01-29 08:21:03.080 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 735, in reraise
01-29 08:21:03.080 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
01-29 08:21:03.081 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
01-29 08:21:03.081 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
01-29 08:21:03.081 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/urllib3/connection.py", line 353, in connect
01-29 08:21:03.081 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/urllib3/connection.py", line 181, in _new_conn
01-29 08:21:03.081 30098 31302 I python  :  urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <botocore.awsrequest.AWSHTTPSConnection object at 0xb9e1ed00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 7] No address associated with hostname
01-29 08:21:03.082 30098 31302 I python  :  
01-29 08:21:03.082 30098 31302 I python  :  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
01-29 08:21:03.082 30098 31302 I python  :  
01-29 08:21:03.082 30098 31302 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
01-29 08:21:03.082 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 37, in <module>
01-29 08:21:03.082 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 678, in download_fileobj
01-29 08:21:03.083 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/s3transfer/futures.py", line 106, in result
01-29 08:21:03.083 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/s3transfer/futures.py", line 265, in result
01-29 08:21:03.083 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 255, in _main
01-29 08:21:03.083 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/s3transfer/download.py", line 340, in _submit
01-29 08:21:03.084 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
01-29 08:21:03.084 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/client.py", line 662, in _make_api_call
01-29 08:21:03.084 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/client.py", line 682, in _make_request
01-29 08:21:03.084 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/endpoint.py", line 102, in make_request
01-29 08:21:03.085 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/endpoint.py", line 136, in _send_request
01-29 08:21:03.085 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/endpoint.py", line 253, in _needs_retry
01-29 08:21:03.085 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/hooks.py", line 356, in emit
01-29 08:21:03.085 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/hooks.py", line 228, in emit
01-29 08:21:03.086 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
01-29 08:21:03.086 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__
01-29 08:21:03.086 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 250, in __call__
01-29 08:21:03.086 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 277, in _should_retry
01-29 08:21:03.087 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 316, in __call__
01-29 08:21:03.087 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 222, in __call__
01-29 08:21:03.087 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
01-29 08:21:03.087 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/endpoint.py", line 200, in _do_get_response
01-29 08:21:03.087 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/endpoint.py", line 269, in _send
01-29 08:21:03.088 30098 31302 I python  :    File "/home/josh/totals/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/botocore/httpsession.py", line 337, in send
01-29 08:21:03.088 30098 31302 I python  :  botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://totals2.s3.amazonaws.com/totals.json"
01-29 08:21:03.088 30098 31302 I python  : Python for android ended.
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
```

Here is my spec file, looking at the issue it cannot resolve an IP per host name....do I need to put the IP of my S3 bucket?

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Totals

# (str) Package name
package.name = myapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd,boto3,botocore,dateutil,urllib3,jmespath,s3transfer

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.7.0

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Comment: line 37 from code is as follows `s3.download_fileobj('totals2', 'totals.json', f) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include permissions. Specifically:

```
android.permissions = INTERNET
```

Might also need to add to `requirements`:

```
openssl, requests, urllib3
```

Also, you might need to do a runtime permissions request:

```
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
request_permissions([Permission.INTERNET])
```

see the [documentation](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis/#runtime-permissions).

Comment: Thanks, @John! I added all those requirements....I also had my permissions tab commented out (DOH) worked great after those two things.